# Translate component name in Installfile Joomla

Tags: joomla, components

how translate the **name of the component** in the Installfile (.xml).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<install type="component" version="1.5.0">
   <name>COMPONENT NAME</name>
```

If the language it's english it's must show "Component Name".
If the language it's spanish it's must show "Nombre del Componente", as a name of my own componet in the **Extensions Manager**.

Thank's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Joomla 1.6 you can translate it. See [docs here](http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_%28MVC%29_Component_for_Joomla!1.6_-_Part_15).

For Joomla 1.5, you can’t.

Answer (score 1):

The component information is stored in the database. Doing it how you have done will not work. I don't think this is supported. A component/product should have 1 name. You shouldn't have different names for your product/component. Microsoft don't call Windows a different name in Spanish, German, etc - you should do the same.